# Skipping an index in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, indexing

I've seen options for only hitting certain numbers in a foreach (if i < 25, etc) but I'm wondering how to best skip a string index completely

I have a loop that works perfectly and I don't want to change what it's doing, I just want to omit one row that has the index of 'employee'

I've tried the below but it doesn't seem to work as I get a syntax error at my if statement

```
foreach ($arr as $row) {
  if($arr[] !== 'employee'){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($colstrs); $i++) {
            $cellstr = $colstrs[$i] . $xrow;
            $ows->setCellValue($cellstr, $row[$i]);
            $ows->getStyle($cellstr)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($this->numfmt);
        }
        $this->setFillColors($xrow);            
        $xrow++;
   }
}
```

Comment: How does one `$row` looks like? Where is the `employee` value?

Comment: `if(!array_key_exists('employee', $arr)) { ... }` assuming you're saying that employee is a key you want to avoid.  If the key exists but can be empty you can use `if(empty($arr['employee'])) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you want to leave the loop body in tact, here is one possible non-destructive approach. Not checking anything on every iteration also saves you a little bit of performance loss. See comments for step-by-step explanation.

```
<?php

// Sample array. We'll be filtering out the first element ('a').
$a = ['a' => 123, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 'foo', 'd' => 'bar', 'abc' => 'def', 'def' => 789];

// Use array_filter() to copy the array on certain condition ($key !== 'a').
// Passing ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY will only pass the key to the callback, saving some memory.
// The original array is left untouched.
foreach (
    array_filter($a, function($key) { return $key !== 'a'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
    as $element
)
{
    var_dump($element);
}

/* Outputs:
int(2)
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "bar"
string(3) "def"
int(789)
*/
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks for this. I see now that there are a few different ways but this gave me the best results

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> continue

**Example**

```
         $rows = array(
                [
                    'id'    => 2,
                    'name'  => 'Jon Doe'
                ],
                [
                    'id'    => 3,
                    'name'  => 'Smith'
                ]
            );
            foreach ($rows as $row){
                // if you are willing to skip who belongs id = 2
                if ($row['id'] == 2)
                    continue;
                
                //Do your business logics
                
            }
```

Comment: Agree. In case you want to skip multiple you can add a `$blacklist` and ask in the if for your continue `in_array($row['id'], $blacklist)`. - Nicely done :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the index from the loop to ignore the employee section like so.

```
foreach ($arr as $string_index => $row) {
  if(strtolower($string_index) !== 'employee'){
    //Content
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that the rest of your variable are defined somewhere else and have only included the part for the index as it was a bit confusing. As you can see, after the 'as' you can use a $variable followed by '=>' then the $individual_row.

That first variable is the index of the array while the second variable is the row.